# Android SMS app support

Tags: android

I'm writing SMS app for android devices. I want to support **15-21 API's**. 
Is there any way to do this?

Of course on some devices my app will crash  , because SMS provider was hidden till android 4.4  because some phone manufacturers had their own implementation of that API. 
But in most cases(I think 95%) my app will work.

Before *Android 4.4* there wasn't *default SMS app concept* , from *Android 4.4* you must be default SMS app  in order to have right to `delete/update`  SMS database rows.

So I have a question , is it possible to support **API level 15-19+**.

Comment: Sure. Only use features supported by that range of API levels.

Comment: what SMS provider  ?

Comment: I mean Telephony API. To make CRUD operations with SMS database , to send and receive SMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem here was to support *Default sms app* that is provided in *19 api*.

*I solved this problem with following approach.*

I  checked phone api level,  than if it was kitkat or newer I was using new api that isn't in api 15 with  `@suppresslint("NewApi")`. this annotiatian allows you to use api , if phone sdk is not lower than the code that you want to use.

So my application thinks that its default sms app when it is working on *api <19* , and asks for setting as default app if it's on *api19>=* or more.

**it's not possible to write working sms app , without this approach.**